# Tratamento de strings com str_replace

Tags: php, string

Estou tentando tratar uma string com a função `str_replace` porém eu queria inserir um `<span>` antes antes do da palavra tratada, como no exemplo abaixo:

```php
$entrada = array("//");
$tratamento   = array("<span class='comentario'>//</span>");
$saida = str_replace($entrada, $tratamento, $mensagem);
```

**Minha dúvida:**

É possível fazer isso com a função `str_replace`, ou apenas com expressões regulares, se for somente com ER's gostaria que, por favor, me dessem exemplos.

Queria que após fazer isso me retornasse algo do tipo:

```html
<span class='comentario'>//</span>
```

Valeu Galera!

Comment: Você quer que transformar uma palavra pré determinada em span, ou quer que tudo entre // e fim da linha entre no span? Se o texto vai variar fora do controle do código, só ER mesmo, ou uma combinação de localização de string inicial e string final, e substituição, que pode ser bem mais rápida que regex/ER.

Comment: @Bacco Eu quero que tudo entre // e fim da linha entre no span, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Exemplo com ER's:**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v38-z5b)

```
$entrada = "/Olá¡ hoje é domingo/";
$saida = preg_replace('/(\/)(.*)(\/)/',"<span class='comentario'>$2<span>",$entrada);
```

Se quiser "apanhar o conteúdo desde `//` até uma nova linha pode usar: `'/\/\/(.*)/'` - [**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mjc-8x1)

Exemplo com explode:

```
$entrada = "//Olá, hoje é domingo";
$entradaArr = explode('//', $entrada);
$tratamento   = array("<span class='comentario'>", "</span>");
$saida = $tratamento[0].$entradaArr[1].$tratamento[1];
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, seria mais o caso de achar desde // até o fim da linha, como //abc123 -> <span>//abc123</span>

Comment: @Bacco, aha, ok. Adicionei essa opção. Vou por exemplo tambem.

Comment: @Bacco, valeu pela ajuda, deu certo aqui [off topic] Você poderia me mostrar alguma coisa para eu entender a lógica das expressões regulares?

Comment: @Odair, veja __[este link](http://regex101.com/r/fQ6aD0)__, é um site excelente para Regex, com a explicação em baixo de cada pedaço.

Comment: Pow, valeu @Sergio vou dar uma estudada sim. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
E, cara! que site massa esse ahaha

Comment: @Bacco, funcionou certinho, o único problema é que não coloca o span só na primeira linha, e sim no meu texto inteiro, tem como alterar isso? Ficou assim minha ER: $text = preg_replace("/(\/\/)(.*)/is",'<span class="comentario">//$2<span>',$text);

Comment: @Odair, penso que você quer escrever `@Sergio`, e não Bacco :) Pode dar-me um exemplo concreto com o seu codigo php?

Comment: Desculpe @Sergio é isso mesmo rs então eu fiz uma função bbcode function BBCode($text) {$text = preg_replace("/(\/\/)(.*)/",'<span class="comentario">//$2<span>',$text);}

Comment: @Odair, e pode colocar um/dois exemplos de uma string que `$text` possa ser?

Comment: Com prazer rs, @Sergio, aqui está o $text que estou tentando tratar com expressões regulares :D http://jsbin.com/xepib/1/edit

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12935/discussion-between-sergio-and-odair)

Comment: @Sergio, desculpa perguntar de novo, mas surgiu outro problema, meu bbcode coloca tag <br> na quebra de linha e aquele exemplo que vc me enviou ele pega depois do \n como posso adptar o script para que ele aplique o span somente até antes da tag <br>?

Comment: @Odair, o que você pode fazer é adicionar um `<br />` a seguir ao span quando faz a substituição.